# Neo4j JavaScript driver (bolt) Cypher query by id not working => error: Expected entity id to be an integral value

Tags: javascript, express, neo4j, cypher

I'm new to Neo4j, working on a React + Express + Node + Neo4j app.

I got the error message

> Expected entity id to be an integral value

when I do [this query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pug2T.png).

But if I changed the `$id` to a hardcoded number i.e. `5`, I got the result and the query worked.

I've also tried passing the param as `{"id":5}` and `{"id": '5'}`, etc... and referencing the param in the query string as `id = {id}` instead of `$id` and tried `p.id` instead of `ID(p)` or `id(p)`.

Please help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want pass natural id from node.js to cypher as param you need convert it to 64-bit integer:

```
var params = { id: require('neo4j-driver').v1.int(5) }
```

Or in the cypher query itself:

```
MATCH (p) WHERE ID(p) = toInteger($id) RETURN p, ID(p) as id
```